# Sequence diagram question

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

For this question:

***Considering the following sequence diagram, it is CORRECT to state that:***

[image]

Select one or more:

a.
Message 4 might never be executed.

b.
Message 5 is not complete until the Customer receives an message confirming creation of the ShoppingCart.

c.
Message 7 corresponds to behaviour belonging to the ShoppingCart class.

d.
Message 6 is an example of a timed event which can only take place after other messages have occurred.

e.
Book and Bookshop are objects.

The correct options are A and C. But I believe the correct option is A and E. E should be correct because Bookshop and Book are clearly objects since they are enclosed in rectangular shapes. Why are options A and C correct and not A and E?

Answer (score 2):

UML uses `Name : Type` notation. Both the name and the type can be elided when irrelevant. The `: ShoppingCart` label describes an unnamed object of type `ShoppingCart`. Since there is only one object of each type, it is not necessary to give names to the objects.

Thus, `Book` and `BookShop` are not objects. They are classes/types, and `: Book` and `: BookShop` indicate unnamed instances/objects of these types. Therefore, answer E is wrong.

The `message7` is invoked on the `: ShoppingCart` object, which means that the `ShoppingCart` class provides such a method. Therefore, answer C is correct. In particular, the `message7` is not part of the `Customer` class/type/actor.

Comment: I'm still confused, how do you know there is only one object of each type? Also you're saying if book and bookshop had names they would be objects?

Comment: @computerscienceisapain Looking at the diagram I see one unnamed actor `: Customer` and three objects `: Bookshop`, `: Book`, and `: ShoppingCart`. Because of the `Name : Type` syntax I see that all of these objects have no name, but that they are instances of the classes `Bookshop`, `Book`, and `ShoppingCart`, respectively. So there is one object of each type. Having a name is not necessary for being an object. To muddle things further, classes are objects in the UML meta-model. Here, the `:` means that the box does not represent that class, but an instance of the class.

Comment: I echo @computerscienceisapain's confusion. To me, the terms "object" and "instance of a class" are interchangeable. The fact an object doesn't have a "name" is irrelevant, in my mind. Perhaps "object" in UML terminology means "a *named* instance of a class?"

Comment: @GregBurghardt I'm not trying to make a distinction between “object” and “instance”.

Comment: Ok, I see the difference -- "e. Book and Bookshop are objects." is not referring to the vertical rectangle in the diagram. It refers to the horizontal rectangles. It's a matter of how the reader interprets the text. The horizontal rectangles with "Book" and "Bookshop" represent classes. The vertical rectangles under them represent the lifetime of the objects. I was focused more on the lifetime of the objects than the classes themselves.

Comment: why are you calling them objects now? You said and I quote: "three objects : Bookshop, : Book, and : ShoppingCart", I am even more confused now @amon

Comment: @computerscienceisapain The `:` is relevant. There is a difference between the class `Book`, and its instance, the object `: Book`.

Comment: So if I am not mistaken. The horizontal rectangles are objects but Book and Bookshop itself are classes? @amon

Comment: @computerscienceisapain yes, in your specific diagram the horizontal boxes represent objects. (Of course, excluding the `opt` frame, which does not represent an object but an optional part of the interaction.)

Comment: I think the confusion is about the meaning of the symbols. First of all, the horizontal rectangles are the head of a _lifeline_. A lifeline _represents_ an _attribute_ or a _parameter_.  The text before the colon is the _name_ of the attribute or parameter, the text after the colon is its _type_. An attribute or parameter can have a multiplicity greater than 1. Even then a lifeline only stands for _one_ _object_ which is an _instance_ of the specified type. Please note: UML doesn't contain instances, only _instance specifications_. All diagrams _specify_ more or less instances.